# Retrieving JSON data from webhook

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to retrieve the “text” property from a JSON via cURL GET from a JSON Webhook. In order to get the information “text”, my app has to get the resource [“id”:”], which is a variable. The JSON is shown here below:

```
{
"id":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL01FU1NBR0UvMzIzZWUyZjAtOWFhZC0xMWU1LTg1YmYtMWRhZjhkNDJlZjlj",   
"roomId":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vY2RlMWRkNDAtMmYwZC0xMWU1LWJhOWMtN2I2NTU2ZDIyMDdi",
"personId":"Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1BFT1BMRS9lM2EyNjA4OC1hNmRiLTQxZjgtOTliMC1hNTEyMzkyYzAwOTg",    
"personEmail":"person@example.com",
"text":"Something interesting and potentially sensitive",
"created":"2016-03-15T07:33:56.767Z"    
}
```

I’m trying to deploy a cURL GET /message/{id}, however, the cURL I’m implementing isn’t working. Follows the code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
echo $data("messages");

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.mysite.com/v1/messages/id",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer MzgwNjUwOGYtZTY4NC00NTIyLTgzNTctZmNiMjI1ZGMxZTdhNzhmYjFmNjYtNzgz",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Follows RAW BODY = 200 OK:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1dFQkhPT0svMzdjZDEzMTktODFkMC00MjMwLWJkOTItNzEzMWE4NjU2YWIx
    [name] => Webhook
    [resource] => messages
    [event] => created
    [filter] => roomId=Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vODEyNDM0NzAtZTllZS0xMWU1LTllZjYtZjFmMDhjMjNjNDI5
    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL01FU1NBR0UvZTg4MjNlODAtZWFiOC0xMWU1LTg4OTYtNDU3YjU0OGEyNzJh
            [roomId] => Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1JPT00vODEyNDM0NzAtZTllZS0xMWU1LTllZjYtZjFmMDhjMjNjNDI5
            [personId] => Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL1BFT1BMRS84MTE3NGUzOC04N2MwLTRmYzUtOTNlOC03NmEzMGY0MWJjZDA
            [personEmail] => person@example.com
            [created] => 2016-03-15T14:19:20.040Z
        )

)
```

Any help please? 
Many thanks!

Comment: What does your cURL code that is actually making the request look like?

Comment: Hi Matt. The cURL code is shown here above. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of things of note here.  Its a little hard to figure out above what is the data  your are trying to retrieve the id from.

1. Your URL looks wrong, you say that you are making a GET to /messages/{id}.  The {id}, means you replace that with your id value.  This is standard syntax for API documentation.  So if I use the ID from your first block of JSON the URL should look like.

/messages/Y2lzY29zcGFyazovL3VzL01FU1NBR0UvMzIzZWUyZjAtOWFhZC0xMWU1LTg1YmYtMWRhZjhkNDJlZjlj

2. If you are trying to retrieve the ID from the very top JSON object you would simply need to use the following.

`$data->id`

3. This is more semantcis but you don't need to use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", if you are just doing a standard GET request.

**Edit**

Its pretty simple, just try this.

```
$webhookResponse = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

//Retrieve the id from the data object, via the id property
$messageId = $webhookResponse["data"]["id"];

$curl = curl_init();

//Add the messageId to the URL
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages/" . $messageId,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer MzgwNjUwOGYtZTY4NC00NTIyLTgzNTctZmNiMjI1ZGMxZTdhNzhmYjFmNjYtNzgz",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: 8be1cfeb-2dda-a5a8-8e04-39af3bdf46e7"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the 'text' property, which comes inside the 'id' inside the data property: { [data] => Array ( [id] => ...) }. Once get this 'id' inside 'data' I will be able to reach the desired 'text'. In order to get "text" I have to deploy a cURL GET to /messages/{id}, where the {id} token is variable changing at any single request. Using the url https://api.mysite.com/v1/messages?id doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: @ Matt: I applied your suggestions, but I'm still not getting the "text" content. Many thanks for the support!

Comment: Just echo out $messageId and confirm its the correct value.  Also, do a var_dump of $response and see what that it.

Also, before the curl_close, you could see if curl gave you any errors by doing:  echo curl_error( $curl );

Comment: It's working perfectly fine. Many thanks for the help! All the best!